# gcd of product of exponents of prime factors and product of prime factors

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $n = \prod\limits_i p_i^{k_i}$.

I want to express 
$$
\gcd(\prod\limits_i k_i, \prod\limits_i p_i)
$$

as an arithmetic function (i.e get rid of gcd).

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think so, just think of $24=2^3\cdot 3^1,25=5^2,26=2\cdot13,27=3^3$ resulting in resp. $3,1,1,3$. Can't think of any arithmetic function that would give you this result, even when knowing $p_i,k_i$

Comment: You cannot get rid of the gcd. Take $i=1$ and $k_1=k$, $p_1=p$, $n=p^k$. Then $gcd(k,p)$ is just $gcd(k,p)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that could be an answer, I think.